# How many LOAD segments will be loaded into memory from a Linux (or BSD) kernel? With any flags?

Tags: c, linux, elf, bsd

While working on a custom linker script, I accidentally created an ELF executable (statically linked) with a single LOAD segment containing all the the program sections.

According to readelf, the segment flags were RWE.

I thought "WTF!" but I was in a hurry and I went back to the task at hand.

Later I realized that such executable was a Very Bad Thing(TM), as the program could modify itself while running, but I'm not able to create it again.

Does anybody know if the Linux or BSD kernels would be fine with such a monster?

It had two "strange" aspects that I've never seen in any other elf executable:

1. a number of LOAD segments != 2
2. a segment marked with RWE

Comment: There's actually linker option for that: `--nmagic`. A program with a single read/write/executable segment isn't really a monster.

Comment: And can it be loaded and executed like any other executable on unix? Also do you know if there is a legitimate reason to create such kind of ELF? Or one with 3 LOAD section?

Comment: You can run such an executable on Linux and I assume BSD. i'd expect any ELF-based system to support it, since not allowing it would requiring having code in the ELF loader that specifically disallowed it. The obvious reason for doing this is so the .text section can be written to, say for self-modifying code.